# Plotting or choosing nth pixel in a binary image MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot

I have a binary image and I found the positions of the ones. I have x and y positions. I plotted from variables tables for example plot(1,94, 'g+'). I have selected every 60th pixel. I wonder is it possible to have a command or code to choose every nth pixel by itself instead of writing manually?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like "extracting every k-th element" [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)?

Comment: I am not sure if it is extracting. I just want to plot them and show in the result. I have a line in binary image i want to show 10 points on it. I wrote manually but i was searching something more practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use indexing `1:n:end`:

```
% generate random binary image
bw = rand(100) > 0.9;
% locate all 1's
[r,c] = find(bw);
% choose every nth pixel
n = 30;
rr = r(1:n:end);
cc = c(1:n:end);
% plot
imshow(bw,'InitialMagnification','fit');
hold on;
plot(cc,rr,'r*');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.

[hy,hx]=find(bwi);
imshow(bw); hold on;
plot(hx,hy, 'ro')

% choose every nth pixel
n = 60;
hx = x(1:n:end);
hy = y(1:n:end);
% plot
hold on;
plot(hx,hy,'g*');

I tried in my code but it only plots one point. I would like to find ten points. Is it possible?

Comment: do `hx = hx(1:n:end); hy = hy(1:n:end);`